# REST conventions: when to use HTTP headers to slightly alter POST behavior to a resource URI?

Tags: rest, http, http-headers

In my application there are several roles users can have, but regardless of what their roles end up being, they go through the same registration process (`POST /users`). The system assigns a role by default, however, there's one particular user type for which registration needs to behave slightly differently. The resource to be created is still pretty much a user, but, in this case, if I want the server side code to alter its behavior a bit, is it advisable or acceptable to use a custom header as some sort of a flag, something like, `Mode: Special`.

Comment: Why can't you put it into the request body?

Comment: @moonwave99 I'm thinking of using HTTP header because the mode flag is not exactly part of the core resource model.

I'm also considering a branching of the URI like, `/users/special` but I'm not sure if that's acceptable by convention.

Comment: Without an example, it sounds like this attribute *is* part of your core resource model; it's just that it can often go unspecified. That would suggest making it a non-required field in the request body. Doing a `CREATE` via `POST` at `/users/special/` would be acceptable if you're then going to `LIST` your special users at `/users/special/` as well. But if you're not yet convinced to put it in the body, I would recommend a query parameter over including it in the header.